# use Reduce with paste and paste0

Tags: r, paste

I have a list here.

```
NewList <- list(a="abc",b="xyz",c="lmn")
```

If I run `Reduce(f = function(x,y){paste0(x,y,sep=";")},x=NewList)`
surprisingly, it gives me     `"abcxyz;lmn;"`

If I run  `Reduce(f = function(x,y){paste(x,y,sep=";")},x=NewList)`, the answer is as expected `"abc;xyz;lmn"`.

Can anyone help me explain why `paste0` gives the results above different from `paste`?

Answer (score 1):

According to `?paste`

> paste0(..., collapse) is equivalent to paste(..., sep = "", collapse), slightly more efficiently.

By providing a new `sep`, it is creating a conflict with the already existing `sep`.  Instead use `paste` with `sep`

---

Here, we can directly use `paste` without any `Reduce` as the `length` of each of the elements of `list` is 1

```
paste(NewList, collapse=";")
#[1] "abc;xyz;lmn"
```

Or

```
paste0(NewList, collapse=";")
#[1] "abc;xyz;lmn"
```

Note that in the above case, we are not touching the `sep`